SpecFlow with repetitive tests
I am getting started with Specflow/Cucumber and I have a scenario that has an enum and I want to run the different sceanarios against each enum value.
As an example, I have an Enum (Alpha, Beta, Gamma) and there are 2 scenarios. So I end up with something like:
Scenario Outline: enum test
Given the <scenario>
When system is called
Then it should result in <result>

Examples:
 | name         | scenario| result      |
 | foo - alpha  | foo     | foo alpha 1 |
 | bar - alpha  | bar     | bar alpha 2 |
 | foo - beta   | foo     | foo beta  1 |
 | bar - beta   | bar     | bar beta  2 |
 | foo - gamma  | foo     | foo gamma 1 |
 | bar - gamma  | bar     | bar gamma 2 |

As you can see this can get really long. Is there some way that I can set this up so I only have to define the scenarios once and can pass in the enum and the value it should would be part of the result.

Can you make your example more concrete? Right now I would say that Gherkin isn't the right tool for the job, but that is in part because you've made your problem very generic.

I have a DatePart enum (Month, Day, Year, Hour,  Minute, Second) that I want to pass into each scenario and test the result. It is the same scenario for each DatePart.  Currently I have setup a scenario outline for each DatePart and copy the table and adjust the expected result.

Ah. That is still a bit generic. But remember that Gherkin is not a programming language. If writing one single scenario with a big data (not example) table can convey the behaviour of the system correctly and clearly than that is perfectly fine. Even if that means you are not reusing step definitions, or if the steps in the scenario become really complex, or if multiple things are being tested at once. If conveying this information is not essential, then you may also not need to use Cucumber and you can probably use some data driven testing paradigm.
